# What Algorithm Does EconomizedRationalApproximation Use?

Tags: approximation

I'm very interested in Approximation Theory, especially with Continued Fractions and Rational Functions.   I really like the approximations that Mathimatica gives with EconomizedRationalApproximation[] because the approximations are always either much better than any method I've been able to find and implement on my own, or they have coefficients that are significantly smaller once the numerator and denominator coefficients are converted to integers.  For the moment I'm specifically interested in the mid-point or one end-point of the range of the approximation to be easily analytically differentiable and ideally with a Taylor Series about that point with Rational Coefficients.  I've seen this applies to many important functions in Mathematics, and it can be useful for finding approximations to integrals and inverses of analytic functions and their compositions.

I've looked into several Chebyshev economization techniques, such as Maehly's Method for Continued Fractions, Mayer's adaptation of the same method, and Ralston's adaptation to successive Pade Approximants as well.  All of these methods at best match the output of EconomizedRationalApproximation, but most of the time they either require much more precise coefficients(read as larger), and/or their error as a function is much further from equiripple than EconomizedRationalApproximation[]'s.

Other methods with similar effectiveness and without requiring extremely precise coefficients would be appreciated as well.   But I want to be clear that a requirement I have of the method is that it's simple to compute the approximation using only the function value and the values of its derivatives at the central point or end point, not something like the Method of Remez that requires evaluating the function many times at many points and iteratively approaching the minimax solution.  Ideally I'd be working with Rational Numbers for functions whose Taylor's Series' yield rational coefficients, as it appears EconomizedRationalApproximation[] does.

I want a method that is effective in its error distribution, but minimal in the required computation to yield a good approximant. I'm not looking for a perfect equiripple approximant, I'm looking for something that's close yet requires very little computation to derive. EconomizedRationalApproximation seems to fit the bill very well, but I'd like to understand how the method works get resources on the method if any are available.  I'd like to be able to implement the method, or a similar method (but better than the ones I've mentioned above) myself, so Books, Article or Paper references with examples would be greatly appreciated.

This is for academic purposes and for my curiosity.  If the method is patented, I'd understand if you can't reveal it, but I would like to know if there's anything that meets the criteria I mentioned while working better than the other methods I've mentioned above.  I've heard about the Cartatheodory-Fejer Method, but it doesn't seem to fit the bill from what I've seen.  But I don't know a lot about it.

Thank you,
jedi945

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I've not looked into it, but the code is in the FunctionApproximations directory which you can locate by executing ``FindFile["FunctionApproximations`"]`` in Mathematica.  The file you want is EconomizedRationalApproximation.m.

Comment: Hello Michael E2, Thank you!   That answers my question.  For those reading here is is Ralston's method, but it appears it uses a different sequence of pade approximants that somehow gave better results for the functions I tried.  Thank you! Feel free to make your comment an answer and I can mark it as the solution.